# CSS Media Query not working for iPad recently

Tags: css, html, ipad, responsive-design, media-queries

I have been using some media queries for the i Pad and they were working fine until two,three day ago. But they just stop working. My i Pad is not recognizing the media queries while they are still working in **Firefox native responsive design test view** and other online websites to check the responsive designs.
My initiative queries are with view port in header

**HTML**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2"/>

@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {  //for landscape

@media screen and (min-width: 755px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation : Portrait) //for portrait.
```

**Then tried these ones too**

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (orientation:portrait){
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)  {
```

---

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape){
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : landscape)  {
```

//Also in addition i tried the other view port meta tag too
like

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2"/>
```

**But no luck**

I don't know where I am doing mistake but this kind a important. Please help any kind of help will be appreciated

Comment: I've noticed issues with my iPad listening to my device-width setting in the meta tag while in portrait view. Does this only happen in a certain orientation for you, too? I can't find anything wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try the meta content:

```
<meta content="True" name="HandheldFriendly">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I tried these tags but still it's not working. I am using all types of queries now like

Comment: Thank you, I have tried the javascript too. But the thing is it's not working on the iPad I have. Though I can see the site portrait view but not like changing with orientation changed and it's not full screen. In addition, I have tried the i Pad emulator it working fine on emulator. Can be my I Pad has some issue or something else?

Comment: For iPad
You can also use media query to detect orientation (portrait or landscapse) on the iPad (credits: Cloud Four).

<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="portrait.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:landscape)" href="landscape.css">

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this was ever working. I believe the issue is because you are using screen, this media type is reserved for regular computer screens.

Here is a list of the media types:

- all: All media devices
- aural: Speech/Sound Synthesizers
- braille: Braille tactile feedback devices
- embossed: Page Braille Printers
- handheld: Small/Handheld Devices (like Smart Phones) [NOTE: Android, iOS, & other smart phone browsers ignore this rule.]
- print: Printers
- projection: Projected Presentations (like slides)
- screen: Regular Computer Screens
- tty: Media that uses a fixed-pitch character grid (like teletypes &
  terminals)
- tv: Television-type Devices

Warmth,
Crystal Miller